# PHP Mail/Postfix always returns true even when Postfix is stopped

Tags: php

I have a weird problem. Using the mail() function and a local Postfix on the server. When Postfix is running, mail gets sent just fine but if I stop Postfix mail() still returns true but no e-mails are obviously sent and no error gets logged anywhere.

Code for sending:

```
echo $accepted; //Returns 0
$accepted = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo $accepted; //Returns 1
```

No other MTAs are running at the server.

Is there any good way of debugging this?

Comment: Why not use something more powerful, like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Postfix may not be running, the mail is still successfully enqueued for sending - on the next start of Postfix it will be processed and sent.

PHP's (internal) `sendmail` call has no way to know, if the MTA is running - just if queueing the mail worked or not.

Comment: This is correct, I just saw this. When I started up Postfix again all the mails were in the queue. Do you have any idea on how to turn off the queue if the MTA is not running?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with postfix short of unmounting (or otherwise making inaccessible) the spool directory

Comment: Under Ubuntu this is at /var/spool/postfix

Comment: @samuelf: There are easier ways of detecting postfix's status. You should be able to do this either with a port scan or checking the return value of an exec() command in php. Add this check before sending in your script and you should be in good shape.

Comment: @BenD Ofcourse there are, but the question was how to make PHP mail() fail, if the MTA is not running - this inly works by making the queue inaccessible. A port scan is a bad idea: Postfix can perfectly well run without any open ports ...

Comment: @Reick, you're right that the port scanner isn't a perfectly reliable method, but it's a "mostly" reliable alternative if you don't have access to exec() etc.